# Stack overflow in Cucumber step definition when re-enqueueing delayed job in .perform

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, delayed-job

I've got a job that is supposed to re-enqueue itself:

```
class TestJob
  def perform
    Delayed::Job.enqueue(TestJob.new, {priority: 0, run_at: 5.minutes.from_now}) 
    true
  end
end
```

I'd like to call its `perform` method in a Cucumber step definition:

```
Then /^the job should run successfully/ do
  TestJob.new.perform.should == true
end
```

However, I get a stack overflow in this step. What's causing this?

Comment: enqueue calls the perform method of TestJob, the perform enqueues again which calls the perform method etc. Infinite loop.

Comment: Why does it call `perform`? It should only put a new entry into the delayed_jobs table as far as I understand.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a 'better' answer out there, but last time I tried to use the enqueue method, it was 'broken'.  By that, I mean I couldn't get it to work.

I do something similar to what you're doing, except that I do

```
TestJob.new.delay(:run_at => 10.seconds.from_now).perform
```